# delete a row from qtableWidget displayed from sqlite database

Tags: python, sqlite, pyqt

i have created an application in which i have to dispaly data from database in a tableWidget and i am successful to display it in table. The issue is I am not getting how to get ID value from a selected row in QTableWidget, in order to delete that row from sql db. Please help me out. This is how i have tried:

```
def removebutton_Clicked(self):
db_id = self.get_currentId()
self.queryCurs.execute("DELETE FROM PATIENT WHERE ID = %d" % (db_id))
self.createDb.commit()

def get_currentId(self):
if self.patientTable.currentIndex():
    index = self.patientTable.currentIndex().row()
    print index
    db_id = self.patientTable.index.value("ID")
    return db_id
```

i am not getting how to get current id of the row of table.....please help me i am stuck

Answer (score 0):

First of all ensure that returned `db_id` is valid value.

```
self.queryCurs.execute("DELETE * FROM PATIENT WHERE ID LIKE ?",[db_id])
```

that will DELETE *(whole row) FROM PATIENT(table) WHERE ID (is)LIKE db_id

For example I have more than one condition in my code:

```
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM Elements WHERE Name LIKE ? OR Type LIKE ? OR Id LIKE ?", [searchWord, searchWord, searchWord])
```

**EDIT** 
since you don't use model in `self.patientTable` you need to populate any column (it can be hidden) of that table with "ID" that you need. 
That way you can take it like this:

```
db_id = (self.patientTable.item(self.patientTable.currentIndex().row(), col).text()).toUtf8()
```

where `col` is column number of column in which you stored ID value

Comment: k but how to get id of that particular row is my question is all about

Comment: So you are saying that `return db_id` does not return correct value? In that case tell me in which column of your `self.patientTable` you populating that value

Answer (score 0):

Are you assuming that the row number in the GUI corresponds with the ID in the database? Don't do that. Database row IDs should remain the same for as long as the row remains in the database table, whereas GUI table displays are far more ephemeral. A side-effect of this is that after a few insertions and deletions, the database table IDs can become non-contiguous and not start at either 0 or 1.

The GUI datamodel needs to have each row of the displayed data remember the ID of the DB table row from where it came — even if it doesn't display this to the user (except maybe for debugging) — so that when you delete the row, you just ask the model to tell you the ID and then delete by that ID. The code is trivial, *as long as you get the GUI model right.*

(This will also allow you to implement sorting by columns easily, if you choose; with identity separated from order and index, you can shuffle stuff any way you want.)

Comment: Also, don't _ever_ substitute values into SQL. Use a parameterised query. It's faster — it can be cached by the DB better — and it's safer and its ever so simple to do.

Comment: Actually i am not using model here i am directly using qtablewidget,

Comment: inside qtablewidget i am displaying table from sqlite database so how can i get id by model as you said in qtablewidget